# recognize a interior highlight

Tags: excel, vba

Okay so I´m trying to recognize everything highlighted with the Dark Blue text 2 lighter 60% and for each value where its true in my range I want to make the cell 2 spaces to the right = 1. I have the below code, any ideas?

```
Sub findcolor()
Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In Workbooks("Report").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B10")
 If cl.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid And cl.Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic And cl.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2 And cl.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105 And cl.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0 Then
        cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "1"
    End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click: 
`Fill Color` icon on the tool bar, and select your color then
`More Colors` from the submenu and custom tab 
now , you can see the three values that make up an RGB(Red, Green, Blue) object for the color you chose
Instead of using all the arguments like you have done - **simply** use the **RGB** object with the three values

```
Sub findcolor()
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10")
        If cl.Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 226) Then
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "1"
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```